# PHP: Is it possible to create a MySQL connection with a function returning mysqli_connect()?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

What I'm trying to do is to create a connection to a MySQL database using a random function that returns (or I wish it would) a mysqli_result. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It returns boolean instead.
The function:

```
function itsName()
{
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $database="";

    return mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
}
```

And when I try to create a connection and use it in a query:

```
$con = itsName();

$query = mysqli_query($con, "ANY QUERY");
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Any normal query doesn't respond with an error, but when I try to, for example, fetch it to an assoc array it gives this error:

> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\site\site.php** on line **X**

It's obvious that `itsName` function returns boolean instead of mysqli_result.

My question is, is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here? To make my function return a mysqli_result instead of boolean.
If so, please help me out with how the code should look like.

And please don't ask why am I even trying to do something like this. Just an experiment.

Comment: Actually, `mysqli_query()` returns you the bool, and not the connection part. You have an error in the query when you get that error. Turn on full error reporting to see what error you're getting from the query.

Comment: Try to check the query's error with `mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: @deceze, may I ask for clarification? The OP makes this statement: *My question is, is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here? To make my function return a mysqli_result instead of boolean. If so, please help me out with how the code should look like.*, seems like Andrius doesn't address the OP's question with his comment...

Comment: i tried, it works. You have probably an error in the query?!

Comment: @Sam Why do you think `mysqli_connect` returns a boolean? If it did, `mysqli_query` would throw an error, not `mysqli_fetch_assoc`!

Comment: Actually @Andrius was just in time, we are telling you the same story. The error is in the query, put the mysqli_connect inside a function works.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
function Connect($hostName = null, $username = null, $password = null, $dbName = null, $port = null, $socket = null, $flags = null)
{
    $link = mysqli_init();
    $link->real_connect($hostName, $username, $password, $dbName, $port, $socket, $flags)
        or die("Failed to connect to the server");
    return $link;
}

$link = Connect("localhost", "username", "password", "db_name");
$link->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1;");
```

You could also use the `real_connect` to detirmine the return:

```
return $link->real_connect($hostName, $username, $password, $dbName, $port, $socket, $flags) ? $link : false;
```

Then have:

```
$link = Connect("localhost", "username", "password", "db_name");
if (!$link)
    die("Failed to connect to the server");
```

But I honestly do not not why you'd want a wrapper for it??

**Note** This uses the OOP approach rather than the pragmatic version you used in your question.

**Edits**

The reason you are getting a bool is because both `mysqli_connect` and `real_connect` both return the `boolean` type, meaning you'd have to create a link of some form and then return it as I have in my `Connect` function example.

**IMPORTANT!** Also, when using `mysqli_init`, you need to ensure that the first mysqli function after is `real_connect`, else you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. I just needed it for a custom method that let me quickly switch between databases.

Comment: @Varelse, but mysqli has a function for this... `$mysqliObect->select_db("db_name");`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get to this yet... Thanks for help!

Comment: @Varelse, I take it you are new to mysqli functionality then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am...

Comment: @Varelse, well, if you need any help, here is the best place, good community and great answers. Do not hesitate to ask a question, I wish you the best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks. :) Though I needed to swich not between databases only, but also between few database servers. And thats why i needed this one actually... Again, thanks for help.